# MySQL which collation can compare Cyrillic and Latin as equal?

Tags: mysql, collation

In my project I need database to return "Dog" if the user inputs in the search field cyrillic letters "Дог" and vice versa. Like transliterated search?...

For Example in Serbia there is officially in use both latin and cyrillic characters... interchangeably. I thought maybe there is a special collation for Serbian Latin and Cyrillic together but as I see there's only separated versions.

Is it possible to do so? How?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure none of the utf8/utf8mb4 collations treat `D`=`Д` (etc).

I suggest you do the following:

- Have an extra column in the table.  It will be the 'romanized' version of the string.  Index this column.  (It can be `CHARACTER SET latin1`; I don't know what would be the best `COLLATION`; perhaps it does not matter.)
- As you insert a row, compute the string for this extra column.
- Also romanize any search string.  Then search against that new column.

Romanizing is probably best done in your app.  To do it in SQL would be a long messy nested `REPLACE(REPLACE(...))`

Comment: Thank you very much fo the answer, @Rick James !
So maybe I should copy the string in the extra column and then use one of [this MySQL transliteration functions](https://pavuk.me/mysql-transliterate-function/)  to transliterate it?

Comment: @AlexFedorin - I like it!  It is likely to be rather slow.  And, as written, it limits the input and output strings to 512 characters.  There could be an issue with the `CHARACTER SET` and/or `COLLATION` _when_ the procedure is declared.

Comment: I actually need it only for titles so i dont think there going to be more than 512 chars. What if i will use utf8mb4 everywhere?

Comment: For Western Europe, including Cyrillic, utf8 and utf8mb4 are identical.  The latter becomes important for Emoji (which might show up in a title?) and Chinese.  Sure, use utf8mb4 everywhere there there might be non-English text.  The extra column could be 'ascii' or 'latin1', since it, by definition, will never have Cyrillic (etc).